# pyspark: collect_list() how to store list of remaining elements of the group per row

Tags: pyspark

My dataset is grouped by two variables: 'customer' and 'sku' using the collect_list() function, I want each row to store a variable how many rows are left in the group.

I have this output:

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---+
|  customer|                 sku|auto_create|        next_creates|  n|
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---+
|248274_ARC|J31/H01N2-D35MM2-...|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  3|
|248274_ARC|J31/H01N2-D35MM2-...|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  3|
|248274_ARC|J31/H01N2-D35MM2-...|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  3|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|318725_ARC|          605/85524V|          N|           [N, N, N]|  3|
|318725_ARC|          605/85524V|          N|           [N, N, N]|  3|
|318725_ARC|          605/85524V|          N|           [N, N, N]|  3|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          N|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          N|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          N|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---+
```

and I want this output:

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---+
|  customer|                 sku|auto_create|        next_creates|  n|
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---+
|248274_ARC|J31/H01N2-D35MM2-...|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  3|
|248274_ARC|J31/H01N2-D35MM2-...|          Y|              [Y, Y]|  3|
|248274_ARC|J31/H01N2-D35MM2-...|          Y|                 [Y]|  3|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|              [Y, Y]|  4|
|297945_ARC|  F87/012V55WH31EX10|          Y|                 [Y]|  4|
|318725_ARC|          605/85524V|          N|           [N, N, N]|  3|
|318725_ARC|          605/85524V|          N|              [N, N]|  3|
|318725_ARC|          605/85524V|          N|                 [N]|  3|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          N|  [N, N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          N|     [N, N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          N|        [N, Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|              [Y, Y]|  6|
|403787_ARC|     BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|                 [Y]|  6|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|        [Y, Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|           [Y, Y, Y]|  4|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|              [Y, Y]|  4|
|434238_ARC|        BB8/40300142|          Y|                 [Y]|  4|
+----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+---+
```

I'm using the following code:

```
w = \
Window.partitionBy('customer','sku').orderBy('customer','sku')
analysis = analysis \
    .withColumn('next_creates', collect_list('auto_create').over(w))
```

Suggestion from answers that threw an error when trying to join:

```
analysis = analysis.withColumn('rownumber',row_number().over(w).alias('rownumber'))

df1 = analysis
df2 = analysis

df1.join(df2, (df1.customer == df2.customer) & (df1.sku == df2.sku) & (df1.rownumber <= df2.rownumber)).groupBy('customer', 'sku').agg(collect_list('auto_create'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are interested in a more spark-like solution: 
you can use rowsBetween for your Window and have something like this:

```
#create a test dataframe
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("318725_ARC","605/85524V","N"), ("318725_ARC","605/85524V","N"),
    ("318725_ARC","605/85524V","N"),("403787_ARC","BPC/77/9601-136","N"),
    ("403787_ARC","BPC/77/9601-136","N"),("403787_ARC","BPC/77/9601-136","N"),
    ("403787_ARC","BPC/77/9601-136","Y"),("403787_ARC","BPC/77/9601-136","Y"),
    ("403787_ARC","BPC/77/9601-136","Y")], ("customer", "sku","auto_create"))

w = Window.partitionBy('customer','sku').orderBy('customer','sku').rowsBetween(0,Window.unboundedFollowing)
analysis = test_df.withColumn('next_creates',collect_list('auto_create').over(w)) 

analysis.show()
```

and the output is:

```
+----------+---------------+-----------+------------------+
|  customer|            sku|auto_create|      next_creates|
+----------+---------------+-----------+------------------+
|318725_ARC|     605/85524V|          N|         [N, N, N]|
|318725_ARC|     605/85524V|          N|            [N, N]|
|318725_ARC|     605/85524V|          N|               [N]|
|403787_ARC|BPC/77/9601-136|          N|[N, Y, N, Y, N, Y]|
|403787_ARC|BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|   [Y, N, Y, N, Y]|
|403787_ARC|BPC/77/9601-136|          N|      [N, Y, N, Y]|
|403787_ARC|BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|         [Y, N, Y]|
|403787_ARC|BPC/77/9601-136|          N|            [N, Y]|
|403787_ARC|BPC/77/9601-136|          Y|               [Y]|
+----------+---------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can introduce "row number" column, you'd possibly be able to perform query like following. Pseudo-code below (didn't test it):

```
df.alias('df1').join(df.alias('df2'), 
  on=
     col('df1.customer')==col('df2.customer') 
     && col('df1.sku')==col('df2.sku') 
     && col('df1.rownum') <=col('df2.rownum') 
 )
.groupBy('df1.customer', 'df1.sku', 'df1.auto_create')
.agg(collect_list('df2.auto_create'))
```

Comment: I changed the syntax of your suggestion a little but the join doesn't want to come through, I'll add what I tried to the post above. Maybe you can see how we can make it work. Thanks for your response!

Comment: is there any error? Try to remove groupBY, egg - see if it works.

Comment: yes:  `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34452.join.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) quantity#154150 missing from ......`and a lot of more error output. I don't even know why he wants 'quantity' its a variable that's also in 'analysis' but we're not manipulating it. I already tried removing groupBy and agg, but the error persists.

Comment: I've tried to add this to my original code: `analysis.withColumn('next_creates', analysis.next_creates[analysis.rownumber-1:])` , in an attempt to select only the relevant part of the list, but that did not work. error thrown: Can not mix the type

Comment: `quantity` is quite confusing. however, I can see you're referring `customer` and `sku` fields without specifying DataFrame alias. that might be related.

Comment: nope, same error! What do you think of my approach in the previous comment?

Comment: Is that from documentation? I've never seen such statement.

Comment: That's python syntax to take a part of a list. e.g. list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] . if you would do list2 = list1[2:] you would get [3,4,5] as output. I was hoping there was a pyspark alternative for that

Answer (score 0):

solution:

I added a column 'rownumber':

```
df = df.withColumn('rownumber',row_number().over(w).alias('rownumber'))
```

then I changed the length of the 'next_creates' as follows:

```
df = df.withColumn('next_creates', df.next_creates[rownumber-1:])
```